# Not able to display buttons in the screen

Tags: android

[image]I am having a screen which has many layouts having title,list view ,comment and buttons but buttons are not getting displayed at all,after list view display I am getting a huge amount of empty space after which comment is getting displayed and buttons are not seen ,this is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="12345617890" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@android:color/black"
                android:text="Ramakrisha Tripati" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="9876543210" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="13/1/2015" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Rohit Sharma" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="item#\nstyle#"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="M Wt\nD Wt\nCS Wt"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Making\nD Rate\nCS Rate"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Margin\nDis %\nDiscount"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="GT\nFSP"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:divider="#00000000"
            android:dividerHeight="5dp"
           />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25dp"

            android:text="Comment" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Comment goes here"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:onClick="accept"
            android:src="@drawable/accept"
            />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why don't you put a text on(but not over) your button?

Comment: Your linearlayout where Your listView is inside has height attribute match_parent, it overlays Your button

Comment: what changes has to be made???please help

Comment: The android:layout_height in the LinearLayout that immediately encloses your ListView is set to match_parent.  Thus, it is taking up all the room (height) in its parent view and since it shares the parent view with your Button, there is no space left for your button to be seen. An easy way to check would be to change the layout_height in that LinearLayout to wrap_content

Comment: but both buttons are not getting displayed

Comment: @Laura comments part is showing just below list,but the buttons is not getting displayed ,please show me a example

Comment: I can't write code now, but I would suggest that you look up the weightsum property for linearlayouts.  One easy way for you to control your vertical space would be to use the weightsum property on the parent and then assign proportional heights to the children with the weight property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your layout code and now the button has appeared.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="12345617890" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@android:color/black"
                android:text="Ramakrisha Tripati" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="9876543210" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="13/1/2015" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Rohit Sharma" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="item#\nstyle#" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="M Wt\nD Wt\nCS Wt" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Making\nD Rate\nCS Rate" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Margin\nDis %\nDiscount" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="GT\nFSP" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:divider="#00000000"
            android:dividerHeight="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Comment"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Comment goes here"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:onClick="accept"
                android:src="@drawable/accept" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put your main LinearLayout inside scrollview and you will see thr buttons.

And if not so maybe your image is so small or transparent.
check with another image maybe.